# How do I call Delphi functions in a bpl from an executable?

Tags: delphi, bpl

I have a Delphi application that I have written a fairly simple wrapper .exe for.

Basically, there was a dll that had a bunch of functions, one of which I would call iteratively once my wrapper did what it needed to. I am not in control of this dll file, and will never be.

Well, now this DLL is a BPL, and I'm not sure how to call functions within that file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easy way to use functions from a package is to "use" the unit that contains the function, call it as usual, and put the package on the list of your project's runtime packages. For that to work, there are a few requirements:

1. Your project must use the same Delphi version as was used to compile the package.
2. You must have access to the DCU file for the unit, or at least the DCP file for the package.
3. The package must exist in the operating system's search path when your program starts.

If you can't satisfy the third requirement, or if you don't want to have the package loaded all the time, then you can call `LoadPackage` for it instead. The way to make that work is to have another package that *is* loaded all the time. It will be used by both your project and the package you wish to load. The intermediate package will expose an interface (such as some registration functions, a variable, or a class) that the main package can use to tell the application what its functions are. You won't be able to "use" the main package's unit in your application directly.

If you can't satisfy the first two requirements, then there is the much harder way, which is also what you'd need to do if your application isn't written in Delphi or C++ Builder. Treat the package like an ordinary DLL. Load it with `LoadLibrary`. Use `GetProcAddress` to load its `Initialize` function, and then call it. (Remember that the calling convention is `register`, not `stdcall`.) Then load the address of the function you wish to call, keeping in mind that the name of the function has been mangled to include some unit and type information. Call the `Finalize` function before you call `FreeLibrary`. Check the source for `LoadPackage` and `UnloadPackage`; whether you need to call `CheckForDuplicateUnits` probably depends on whether you can satisfy requirement number 1.

Comment: Any way you can point me to a resource for doing this? I'm actually not a Delphi programmer, so I'm at a loss for some of this stuff.

Comment: I'm not aware of any resources describing how to "manually" load packages the way I outlined in the final paragraph. The normal way of using packages, as described in the penultimate paragraph, is something I'd expect to appear in the Delphi help, although I can't check that myself since I don't have Delphi installed anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

A BPL is just a DLL with a few specific additions to it.  You should have no trouble calling functions from it just like you did with the DLL, with one specific caveat:  The BPL has to be built in the same version of Delphi as you're using.  This can be a major drawback if you don't have the source code.  If this is a problem for you, you should probably talk with whoever created it and ask them to make it back into a DLL.

Comment: -1, I strongly disagree with the 'Back to DLL-Hell' idea. BPL's offere a very rich interface, and transparent memory management.

Comment: Whether or not you like the implications of it doesn't change the objective fact that you can't load a BPL from a Delphi executable compiled with a different version of Delphi.  If you know a way to do so, I'd be *very* interested in knowing how...

Comment: BPLs can certainly be built with a different Delphi version, if one sticks to the DLL interface and DLL-compatible types (no strings for a start).

Comment: Yes, but you know what I mean.  A way to use the extended BPL features from a different Delphi version. AFAIK it can't be done.

Comment: Mason, A BPL offers a DLL interface plus, if you use the right Delphi, Objects, Interfaces and all other Delphi types. Delphi's version policy is a bit of a pain but well known, just upgrade or downgrade.

Comment: Henk: Yes, that's exactly what I was saying.  The problem is that using a BPL supplied by a third party leaves you tied to that version and unable to upgrade or downgrade unless they do too.  This is why why no experienced Delphi developer uses binary-only component packages, for example.

Comment: Henk, merely using DLLs does not create "DLL hell." If it did, then BPLs would be no different anyway, since they are DLLs. Nor does using packages solve any of the problems that occur in DLL hell. DLL hell is the problem of managing conflicting versions of a DLL in a single install location. You can just as easily have conflicting versions of a BPL.

Comment: Rob, you are right about the general meaning of DLL-Hell, I used the term thinking about the effort it requires to transfer a simple string or array of records. And BPL's do solve most of those DLL problems.

Answer (score 1):

A BPL can eliminate a lot of DLL problems. If you can statically link it, the border becomes all but transparent. If you have to load it dynamically, you need one DLL-style access function  (usually one that returns an object or an interface) and some common type (interface) definitions. All that should be supplied by the maker of the BPL.

Comment: What would be the benefit of making a "dll that had a bunch of functions, one of which I would call" into a BPL? None of the benefits you cite seem to matter for the OP. Maybe he didn't suffer any of those DLL problems either?

Comment: Depends on the parameters of that function. Mayb Dan can post a header line.